# How to UPDATE or DELETE Derby Table fields of Java Objects with custom data type

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, derby

I have a Derby database with table for Java Objects. I have even created a custom data type of the class objects belong to.

The name of the custom data type is MYCURRENCY.

Now, while I can Insert data into table, am getting error during UPDATE & DELETE with Where clause.

```
Error - java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Comparisons between '"APP"."MYCURRENCY"' and '"APP"."MYCURRENCY"' are not supported. Types must be comparable. String types must also have matching collation. If collation does not match, a possible solution is to cast operands to force them to the default collation (e.g. SELECT tablename FROM sys.systables WHERE CAST(tablename AS VARCHAR(128)) = 'T1')
```

My query for Updating :

```
query = "UPDATE CURRENCYTABLE SET currency = ? WHERE CAST(currency as MyCurrency) = ?";
                    pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
                    pstmt.setObject(1, newCurr);
                    pstmt.setObject(2, oldCurr);
```

For Deleting:

```
query = "DELETE FROM CURRENCYTABLE WHERE CAST(currency as MYCURRENCY) = ?";
                    pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
                    pstmt.setObject(1, curr);
```

The class from which objects are created has overriden equalsto & compareTo methods.

Please help in understanding how to compare Java objects in database without Hibernate (its a Swing Project)

Comment: I recreated your error. I don't think it is possible to perform a direct object-to-object comparison, like this, in your SQL. If you look at the [examples here](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/ref/rrefsqljcreatetype.html#rrefsqljcreatetype), they show usages where there is not a direct comparison, or where a Derby user-defined function is required: _"Using functions, you can access fields inside UDTs in a SELECT statement"_. So, I think you need to build Derby functions which are the equivalent of the Java `equals()` and/or `compareTo()` methods.